# How to pass a discriminated union from C# to a F# function (F# - C# interop)

Tags: c#, .net, f#, interop

Definition of the model:

```
type ItemEvent =
| ItemCreated of ItemCreated
and ItemCreated = { timestamp:DateTime; id:ItemId; name:string; description:string option } interface IEvent
```

Here is the interface with the method that I want to call:

```
type IItemWriteAccess =
    abstract Update: ItemEvent -> Result<unit, DomainMessage>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
public class ItemEventHandlers
{
    private readonly IItemWriteAccess _repository;

    public ItemEventHandlers(IItemWriteAccess repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void Handle(ItemCreated msg)
    {
        if(msg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("msg");

        _repository.Update(msg); // this doesn't work
    }
}
```

This produces the following error message:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DomainModels.ItemCreated' to 'DomainModels.ItemEvent'
```

Upcasting to `ItemEvent` also doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You probably want to use `ItemEvent msg` in the c#

Comment: Yeah, probably like this `ItemEvent.NewItemCreated(new ItemCreated(...)` - I'll try that.

Comment: It works like this: `_repository.Update(ItemEvent.NewItemCreated(msg));`

Comment: what's a DU? also, if you found an answer for your own question, remember you can post it too, after some time has passed

Comment: @knocte thx for pointing that out. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Update` takes an `ItemEvent`, an `ItemCreated` instance cannot be passed as an argument.

I have to create an `ItemEvent` and pass the `ItemCreated` instance to the constructor function like this:

```
var @event = ItemEvent.NewItemCreated(msg);
```

Then I can pass it to `Update`:

```
public void Handle(ItemCreated msg)
{
    if(msg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("msg");

    var @event = ItemEvent.NewItemCreated(msg);
    _repository.Update(@event);
}
```